# Extracting data from xmm register to 'standard' variables, intrinsic

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, sse

How can I extract 2 bytes or any amount of bytes from xmm register?

Currently I am using an array to dump the whole register and then I access the bytes that I want. However that seems not as efficient as it could be. Is there a way to efficiently get just the bytes I am interested in?

(I am working in C on Linux 64bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mnemonics for the instructions you probably want are `MOVD` and `MOVQ` and corresponding intrinsics are `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` and `_mm_cvtsi128_si64`.

Answer (score 2):

With SSE2, you can find _mm_extract_epi16 and _mm_insert_epi16 in the <emmintrin.h> header.

SSE4.1 adds _mm_extract_epi8, _mm_extract_epi32, _mm_insert_epi8, and _mm_insert_epi32 in the <smmintrin.h> header.

You can search on any of these to find the exact syntax and semantics, but in general the "extract" forms take two arguments:  An __m128i and a constant integer representing the index.  The "insert" forms take an __m128i, a value, and an index.

Answer (score 1):

In SSE4.1 introduced the [INSERTPS](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/lin/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse41_reg_ins_ext.htm) and [PINS](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/lin/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse41_reg_ins_ext.htm) instructions read 8, 16 or 32 bits from an x86 register memory location and insert it into a field in the destination XMM register given by an immediate operand.

The [EXTRACTPS](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/lin/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse41_reg_ins_ext.htm) and [PEXTR](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/lin/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse41_reg_ins_ext.htm) read a field from the source XMM register and insert it into an x86 register or memory location.